# Determine whether the series $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} \frac{n + \sqrt{n}}{2n^3 -1}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Determine whether the series $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} \frac{n + \sqrt{n}}{2n^3 -1}$ converges?

**My answer:**
For large n, the given series is smaller than $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty}\frac {2n}{2n^3}$ which is equal to $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{n^2}$, but we know that the later is convergent by the p-series test, then by comparison test the given series is convergent.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: It is correct, however you glossed over the exact details of how we know $\frac{n+\sqrt{n}}{2n^3-1}$ is smaller than $\frac{2n}{2n^3}$ for large enough $n$.  It would be best to show this more explicitly.

Comment: It is correct. In fact the inequality holds for all $n$. Just verify it carefully to make the argument complete.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think it does not hold for $n=1$

Comment: @hopefully Right. It is true for all $n>1$.

Comment: you mean by induction starting from say $n =2$ @JMoravitz

Comment: Also, because the Comparison Test applies only to series with nonnegative terms, you should mention that $\frac{n + \sqrt{n}}{2n^3 -1}>0$.

Comment: @hopefully yes, induction should be used for most acceptable forms of proof for this.  As mentioned below however, it is going to be much easier to prove that $\frac{n+\sqrt{n}}{2n^3-1}$ is smaller than $\frac{2n}{n^3}$ instead.  It may not be as tight of a bound, but it is much more convenient to work with and still accomplishes the desired goal.  Remember your examples... $\frac{3}{2}<\frac{4}{2}$ while $\frac{2}{3}>\frac{2}{4}$.  Smaller the numerator, smaller the fraction.  Larger the denominator, smaller the fraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost correct.

You have to make the denominator smaller, not larger.
So yse $n^3$ and everything is fine.

Comment: could not understand what do you mean?

Comment: I think for large n increasing the denominator by 1 would not matter,  because I have increased the numerator also.

Comment: yeah I got it ....great!